# Using ajax to call php and return multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am trying to use javascript to call a php script which then will return multiple variables back to my javascript so I can manipulate them.

This is my JS.

```
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: { id : lastFileId },
                    success: function(output) {
                        alert(output);
                    }
                });
```

my PHP

```
<?php
    $fileId = ($_GET['id']);
    $num1 = 1;
    $num2 = 2;

?>
```

From here, how can I return variables $num1 and $num2 so i can use them in my javascript. Is it possible?

also this is a very basic idea of what I have planned to do if I can achieve this.

Comment: return json (use json_encode in PHP) and add the parameter datatype: json to your ajax request.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can return as many variables as you want with `json_encode()`.

Try in your PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array($num1, $num2));
?>
```

You can add to that array `, $num3, $num4, ...` and so on.

In your JS, you can access each number as follows.

**First**, you will need this line of code to parse the encoded JSON string, in your success function.

`var result = $.parseJSON(output);`

That sets `result` as a JSON object. Now you can access all fields within `result`:

- `result[0]` -- `$num1` in PHP
- `result[1]` -- `$num2` in PHP

Comment: When i do console.log(output[0]), it gives me ' [ '

Comment: It splits up each char as an element, this is not correct

Comment: My mistake, I forgot a line of code. You'll need `var result = $.parseJSON(output);`. See corrected post.

Answer (score 5):

You can go for Json in PHP and javascript if you want array in response for a ajax request

### PHP Code

```
<?php
    $fileId = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:0;
    echo json_encode(array("field"=>$fileId,"num1"=>1,"num2"=>2));
?>
```

### Js Code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert(response.num1);
    }
});
```

Comment: When I do resp.num1 i get "undefined" in my console

Comment: I'm getting the same "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

convert json to object

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
       item=JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(item);
        alert(item.num1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simply string and explode(split) it further in ajax response. Here is PHP code

```
<?php
   $fileId = ($_GET['id']);
   echo $num1."|".$num2;
?>
```

Now split(explode) the response with JavaScript

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'test.php',
        data: { id : lastFileId },
        success: function(output) {
             var my_arr = output.split("|");
             console.log(my_arr[0] + "" + my_arr[1]);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply return it like that
`return ['num1'=>$num1,'num2' => $num2];`

and also, you can access it as followed,
`respone.num1`